# Is there simple way to update Billing address with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, address

I'm trying to update Billing address with Custom button JavaScript.

But I can't update Billing address parts, as it seems there are taken from primary contact.

Here is example, what I want to do:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")} 

var account = new sforce.SObject("Account"); 

account.id = "{!Account.Id}"; 
account.BillingStreet = "test" //here is my problem

sforce.connection.update([account]); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: By the way, are you getting an error message at the problem line?  It's not totally clear where things are breaking down from your question.

Comment: Now its working.
I did get undefined on it. 
Looks like I was pretty tired when doing this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm), Account.BillingStreet is updateable, so you might check the field level security for the running user to see if they're allowed to update that field.

[image]

Secondarily, a Visualforce Page and an Apex Controller, while more verbose then some javascript may be a better way to go, if only for the fact that APEX gets better support on this forum (I know, not much of a reason) and attention from Salesforce than the AJAX toolkit, which is a relic from the now deprecated S-Control family. (Yes, not much of a reason, I know)

Comment: Have to agree, though it may not seem like a good reason, it's enough reason for me to go with Apex for most situations

Comment: Lol, now if only we could use the vf page action attribute without having to worry about security holes (i.e. be able to flag whether a custom button should post to a visualforce page, or do the standard get request)

Comment: We can hope right???  Lol